# The complex conjugate transpose in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, linear-algebra

Is there an existing function for the complex conjugate transpose in Mathematica? The equivalent in matlab is the to the [apostrophe operator](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/fixedpoint/ref/ctranspose.html) (').

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your title you ask for conjugate transpose. That's just `ConjugateTranspose`.

If you want the conjugate, it's just `Conjugate`.

```
Input:
a = {{3 + 2 I, 1 - I}, {2 - 5 I, 4 + 3 I}}
ConjugateTranspose[a]

Output:
{{3 + 2 I, 1 - I}, {2 - 5 I, 4 + 3 I}}
{{3 - 2 I, 2 + 5 I}, {1 + I, 4 - 3 I}}
```

You can also use the Hermitian conjugate symbol, which you use by entering `esc hc esc` or `\[HermitianConjugate]`.

Comment: Or, `\[ConjugateTranspose]` accomplishes the same thing.

Comment: Is ConjugateTranspose exactly what (') does in Matlab?

Comment: @BlueCoffee You should describe exactly what (') does in MATLAB.

Comment: @BlueCoffee How about looking in the manual page at http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ConjugateTranspose.html? It looks like a 1 min read should suffice.